# Finding the most phonetically similar word from WordNet

Tags: nlp, similarity

Besides soundex and other libraries, that take two words and determine whether they are similar, is there any way to find the most similar sounding word from WordNet, for a given word? I tried to use autospell as a well to correct the spelling, but unable to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [e-speak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) to convert your words into a phonetic alphabet. What you can also do is use fuzzy-matching. Here is a nice [blog post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1848528) about this.

Comment: Looking for a text processing solution wrt WordNet